# Create an Alfresco site programmatically in java

Tags: java, rest, alfresco, alfresco-share

Does anybody know how to create an alfresco site from java? I found two api calls that are supposed to create a site:

1) POST /alfresco/service/api/sites. This successfully created a site but when i try to go to the site on alfresco it gives me this error:

> A server error has occured.
>
> There are a number of reasons why this could have happened:
>   You have attempted to access a page that does not exist - check the URL in the address bar.
>   You have attempted to access a page that is not accessible to you, such as a private Site dashboard.
>   A valid page has been requested but the server was unable to render it due to an internal error - contact your administrator.
>
> Return to your dashboard page
>
> Alfresco Software Inc. © 2005-2013 All rights reserved.

2) POST /share/service/modules/create-site which gives me a 401 unauthorized. I am passing in the correct alfresco authentication ticket. Does anybody have any experience creating a site programmatically? Preferably with java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alfresco 4.2.c rest api: create site giving error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255171/alfresco-4-2-c-rest-api-create-site-giving-error)

Comment: @Gagravarr I am getting a 401 unauthorized. That URL creates a site, but I cant access it. From what I can see the second URL is the correct one to use but I get a 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: Just a guees, but it's not maybe that after creating a site you need to add your user (guess admin) to the sites manager group?

Comment: Well I fought this one two weeks ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251706/how-to-create-site-in-share-programmatically The site needs to be created with the Share REST API, otherwise the site preset (ie dashboard etc) is not set up correctly (design flaw if you ask me).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in python. Maybe it helps you also in Java.

First make a Post to the DoLogin Page of Share to get the JSESSIONID Cookie, the alflogin and the alfusername

```
h1 = httplib.HTTPConnection(127.0.0.1,8080) 
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
pa = "username="+username+"&password="+password
h1.request("POST","/share/page/dologin",pa,headers)
response = h1.getresponse().getheaders()
```

Now split the response for JSESSION ID, alfusername and alflogin

```
cookie = jsessionid +"; "+alflogin+"; "alfusername+";"
value = {"title": "Test Side", "visibility":"PUBLIC", "description":"Add descripton here","sitePreset": "MySitePreset", "shortName": "test_side"}
headers2 = {"Content-type":"application/json", "Accept":"application/json", "Cookie": cookie}
# Get Request on any Share Page to get in touch with Share 
request.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/page/user/admin/dashboard", auth=(username,password), headers=headers2)
request.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/share/service/modules/create-site", auth=(username,password), data=json.dumps(value), headers=headers2)
```

That creates an Alfresco Site that also can be accessed

Answer (score 0):

If you use Alfresco version 4.1.4 or above the problem could be in CSRF policy, introduced in that version. More information you can find here: http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/ewinlof/2013/03/11/introducing-the-new-csrf-filter-in-alfresco-share/

Also here: http://ecmstuff.blogspot.ch/2012/03/creating-alfresco-share-sites-with.html you can find a very good tutorial which worked for me. 
You can find working project on github: https://github.com/streetturtle/Alfresco/tree/master/AutomaticSiteCreation